# Error with tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I  was able to run my app on tomcat server but I dont know what went wrong. It's  an issue with `tomcat`.

It shows the error like :

**Tomcat error:**

```
22 Apr, 2013 9:59:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Program Files\AuthenTec TrueSuite\;C:\Program Files\AuthenTec TrueSuite\x86;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter\Driver;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\Lenovo\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Apps Sync\;C:\Program Files (x86)\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_43\bin,C:\Program Files\Java

22 Apr, 2013 9:59:41 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:DynProj' did not find a matching property.

22 Apr, 2013 9:59:41 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Mydynproj' did not find a matching property.

22 Apr, 2013 9:59:41 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:beerV1' did not find a matching property.

22 Apr, 2013 9:59:41 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MyWebLibrary' did not find a matching property.

22 Apr, 2013 9:59:42 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]

22 Apr, 2013 9:59:42 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]

22 Apr, 2013 9:59:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 493 ms

22 Apr, 2013 9:59:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina

22 Apr, 2013 9:59:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.37

22 Apr, 2013 9:59:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
        java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MyWebLibrary]]
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MyWebLibrary]]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
            ... 7 more
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [Book] and [pack2.Book] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/Book] which is not permitted
            at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:335)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2412)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2125)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2080)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2073)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1300)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
            ... 7 more

22 Apr, 2013 9:59:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
        java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
            ... 7 more

22 Apr, 2013 9:59:43 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
        org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8004]]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
            at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
            ... 7 more
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
            ... 9 more
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
            ... 11 more

22 Apr, 2013 9:59:43 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1268 ms
```

Please send me the answer.
thanks

Comment: What frameworks does the webapp use? This detail is not enough also share complete startup logs, some startup activity failed for this app.

Comment: Removed your mail-id from question. Get your answer directly from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the error here

```
The servlets named [Book] and [pack2.Book] 
are both mapped to the url-pattern [/Book] which is not permitted
```

The way what you mapped these servlets in web.xml is not correct.

Your mapping should be

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet logicalname</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Here complete servlet name with package name</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet logicalname</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/url pattern</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

and you can give one url pattern to only one servlet .You can  not give same url - pattern to multiple servlets.Check this also

Comment: @Mayur Gupta can u show your web.xml for me

Comment: @Mayur Gupta did you solve the problem

Comment: hey u did it awesome man ..... @psk...

Comment: @psk i havent seen that silly thing

Comment: is it worked now for u

Comment: @Mayur Gupta is it is working for you now

Comment: @PSR This is not the way to educate users about accepting answers. Many answers might not ever get an upvote or be accepted. Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145987/how-to-educate-new-users-about-accepting-answers

Comment: @andyb ok sorry for mistake.from next time onwards i will provide alink to how to accept answers.Thanks for useful information.Otherwise i may continue in this approach

Comment: @PSR Don't worry about it! I was just passing on some useful information someone else told me about some time ago :-)